# ErrorController para cada módulo no ZF1

Tags: php, zend

Tenho um projeto que usa Zend Framework 1. Ele tem 2 módulos: ***default*** e **admin**.

Quando acontece um erro ou *exception*, o Zend direciona para o ErrorController.

O problema é o seguinte: quando acontece um erro dentro do módulo "*default*", ele direciona para o ErrorController do módulo "*default*" (isso está correto). Porém, quando acontece um erro no módulo "admin", ele também direciona para o ErrorController do módulo "*default*", fazendo com que o erro apareça no *layout* do *site*, ao invés de no *layout* do admin.

Eu possuo um ErrorController no módulo "admin" e achava que isso era automático. Como faço para direcionar os erros do módulo "admin" para o seu ErrorController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720037/zend-framework-module-based-error-handling

Você pode implementar um plugin para examinar a sua requisição e baseado no módulo que você estiver acessando ele seta o ErrorController específico...

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Plugin_ErrorControllerSwitcher extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        if (!($front->getPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler') instanceof Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler)) {
            return;
        }
        $error = $front->getPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler');
        $testRequest = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
        $testRequest->setModuleName($request->getModuleName())
                    ->setControllerName($error->getErrorHandlerController())
                    ->setActionName($error->getErrorHandlerAction());
        if ($front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($testRequest)) {
            $error->setErrorHandlerModule($request->getModuleName());
        }
    }
}
```

Então utilize o exemplo abaixo para registrar o plugin no seu frontController

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front -> registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_ErrorControllerSwitcher())
```

Comment: Eu tinha procurado no SOen e não achei. Funcionou certinho. Valeu!